# Lifehacks Site and voting icons

Tags: discussion

I'd like to propose/suggest a light bulb to be the site's icon as well as for it's voting icons.

Why a light bulb?

Light bulbs are commonly related to **ideas** , I think that an out-of-the-box(life-hack) solution comes from an idea, something you think about and discovered it worked.

I'd like to suggest something similar(since I don't own the rights for the light bulb vector) to this:

[image]

Obviously the coloring is not what I'm proposing, it's more about the idea of a light-bulb as the icon for the site.

Comment: Right now, we are still a beta site and do not get a design. It will be possibly to bring this up once we graduate, though.

Comment: Oh, well that makes a lot of sense, thanks @michaelpri

Comment: It's a cool idea though, @Just. On my main site, we have a [thread](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/321/design-ideas-for-gardening-stackexchange-com) solely for post graduation design ideas.

Comment: Should we start one as well? @J.Musser